# Azure Website deploy from git (bit bucket) - Bad file number

Tags: git, azure

I am having difficulties deploying an Azure Website from BitBucket using the in build deployment settings.

The error message in the log is:

```
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch external --progress
```

Deploy worked perfectly up until recently, when we moved the site to a larger server.

I am aware that the bad file number error often relates to port 22 not being accessible (perhaps due to firewall settings), but there are no endpoint/firewall settings available for Azure Managed Websites.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new site with *exactly* the same details as the previous site got deployment working again.

It looks like "scaling" an azure website breaks the git configuration, preventing it from being able to re-deploy on the new server.

I hope this helps someone else!